# dereferencing a pointer to set a value vs. assigning an address to the pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers

Could someone explain the difference between the following two snippets of code?
In the function below, `*frame_id` maybe a `nullptr`, it's basically the output parameter in the function.

```cpp
bool LRUReplacer::Victim(frame_id_t *frame_id) {
  long oldest_ts = std::numeric_limits<long>::max();
  for (auto & it : this->LRUCache){
    if (it.ts < oldest_ts){
      oldest_timestamp = it.ts;
      *frame_id = it.frame_id;
    }
  }
```

vs.

```cpp
bool LRUReplacer::Victim(frame_id_t *frame_id) {
  long oldest_ts = std::numeric_limits<long>::max();
  for (auto & it : this->LRUCache){
    if (it.ts < oldest_ts){
      oldest_timestamp = it.ts;
      frame_id = &it.frame_id;
    }
  }
```

in the first case, we are assigning `frame_id`  the value of `it.frame_id` and in the second case we are assigning the pointer the address of `it.frame_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first loop, if `it.ts < oldest_ts` you will assign the value of `it.frame_id` to the `frame_id_t` to which `frame_id` points. After the loop is done, the `frame_id_t` instance (`*frame_id`) will hold the last value that was assigned to it.

In the second loop, you will instead assign the address of `it.frame_id` to the `frame_id_t*` (`frame_id`). After the loop is done, `frame_id` will point at the last `it.frame_id` it was set to point at.

Comment: Accepting this as this made the most sense to me.

Answer (score 4):

Let's consider a simplified example doing basically the same as reading/writing/dereferencing is concerned:

```
void f1(int* value)
{
    *value = 1;
}

int g_value = 1;

void f2(int* value)
{
    value = &g_value;
}

int main()
{
    {
        int value = 2;
        f1(&value);
        std::cout << value << '\n'; // prints 1
    }


    {
        int value = 2;
        f2(&value);
        std::cout << value << '\n'; // prints 2
    }
}
```

Note that you just reassign the parameter in the second alternative. The parameter was a pointer value that was passed by value and therefore there is absolutely no effect for the variable the pointer the caller passed a points to.

In C++ using a reference is preferrable:

```
void f3(int& value)
{
    value = 1;
}

int main()
{
    int value = 2;
    f3(value);
    std::cout << value << '\n'; // prints 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first one is replacing a value pointed to by `frame_id` with a new value.  The second is *trying* to replace the given pointer, to make it point to something else.  But it will not work.

You are given a pointer on the stack and resetting it.  That's not going to get passed back to the caller.   He is going to be stuck with the value he passed you.  Unless you pass it by reference

If you wanted the second one to work you would need to change the signature to be this:

```
bool LRUReplacer::Victim(frame_id_t*& frame_id) {
```